# How to install mongosh after installing MongoDB on Windows?

Tags: mongodb, mern, mongo-shell

**The instruction is given but I am not able to understand what is the desired location in my file system here.**

Can anyone clear my doubt?

[image: Instruction of installation of mongosh.]

Comment: It's a single file, there is nothing to install. Copy the `mongosh.exe` file to a folder of your choice. You may add this folder to your `PATH` variable, then you can start it with `mongosh.exe` and you don't need to specify the full path.

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows system, I created a directory `C:\bin` to hold misc executable programs. That directory is added to the `PATH` environment variable.

1. `mkdir c:\bin`
2. `set PATH=c:\bin;%PATH%`
3. Download the zip file, extract `mongosh.exe` to `C:\bin`.